# Google App Engine entities in a separate project are not being dataenhanced

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant, jdo, datanucleus

I have my application entities in a separate project from my main servlet, and they aren't being DataNucleus enhanced.

Not sure if I'm just breaking the rules or what, but setting the ORM setting on the project doesn't enhance my .class files.  The way my workspace is built is by compiling the projects, then running an ant script builds jar files and copies them into the lib directory of my servlet.

I suppose that if I must, I can add some java tasks to my ant scripts to enhance my .class files.  If that's the case, an example of the task would be helpful.

I do want to keep my projects are they are, let me know what I need to do to maintain that.

This is my build.xml of the project containing my entities:

```
<project default="default">

<property name="appengine.sdk.dir" location="C:\superlongpathtomyeclipseplugins\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.5\appengine-java-sdk-1.6.5"/>
<import file="${appengine.sdk.dir}/config/user/ant-macros.xml"/>

<target name="default" depends="dist"/>

<target name="dist">
    <enhance>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${appengine.sdk.home}/lib/*"/>
            <pathelement path="bin"/>
        </classpath>
        <fileset dir="bin" includes="**/*.class" />
    </enhance>
    <jar basedir="bin" destfile="dist\sessionexample.model.jar"/>
</target>
</project>
```

But now here is the error I'm getting:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.(Enhance.java:71)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
>       ... 2 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Key
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getJavaBeanAccessorAnnotationsForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:238)
>       at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AbstractAnnotationReader.getMetaDataForClass(AbstractAnnotationReader.java:128)
>       at org.datanucleus.metadata.annotations.AnnotationManagerImpl.getMetaDataForClass(AnnotationManagerImpl.java:136)
>       at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadAnnotationsForClass(MetaDataManager.java:2278)
>       at org.datanucleus.metadata.MetaDataManager.loadClasses(MetaDataManager.java:385)
>       at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.getFileMetadataForInput(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:743)
>       at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.enhance(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:545)
>       at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1252)
>       ... 7 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.EnhancerLoader.loadClass(EnhancerLoader.java:107)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       ... 18 more

Do I need to keep adding things to my `<classpath>` until it works?

Comment: I think this may get me most of the way there:  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got an ant task to run:

```
<project default="default">

<property name="appengine.sdk.dir" location="c:\pathtoeclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.6.5\appengine-java-sdk-1.6.5"/>
<import file="${appengine.sdk.dir}/config/user/ant-macros.xml"/>

<target name="default" depends="dist"/>

<target name="dist">
    <enhance>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement path="${appengine.sdk.home}/lib/*"/>
            <pathelement path="${appengine.sdk.home}/lib/user/*"/>
            <pathelement path="${appengine.sdk.home}/lib/user/orm/*"/>
            <pathelement path="bin"/>
        </classpath>
        <fileset dir="bin" includes="**/*.class" />
    </enhance>
    <jar basedir="bin" destfile="dist\sessionexample.model.jar"/>
</target>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataNucleus project defines [many ways to run enhancement](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/enhancer.html). It's for you to choose which one makes most sense to your environment and build system. Any other methods not defined on that page are not supported (by us)